# ionic 2 render data before view load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ionic2, ionic-view

I am learning ionic 2 and currently facing some ionic lifecycle issue.
I want to show data after api gets success data.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {LoadingController} from 'ionic-angular';

import WooCommerceAPI from 'woocommerce-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-category',
  templateUrl: 'category.html',
})
export class CategoryPage {

  information: any[] = [];
  infoChild: any[] = [];
  wooApi: any;
  wooCat: any;
  categories: any = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
      this.wooApi = WooCommerceAPI(
          {
            url: 'abc.com/api/v1/cat',

          }
        );
//here also tried to call api

    }


  ngOnInit() {
//here also tried to call api

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("calling api");
    /*from with nginit*/
    this.wooApi.getAsync('products/categories?parent=0').then((data) => {
      console.log("success");
      this.wooCat = JSON.parse(data.body);
      //this.information = this.wooCat;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.wooCat.length; i++) {
        console.log("in for loop");
        this.wooApi.getAsync('products/categories?parent=' + this.wooCat[i].id).then((data) => {
          console.log("get success", i);
          let wooChild = JSON.parse(data.body);
          for (let x = 0; x < wooChild.length; x++) {
            this.infoChild.push(wooChild[x]['name']);
          }
          //console.log(this.infoChild)
          this.information.push({
            'items': {
              'name': this.wooCat[i]['name'],
              'children': [{
                'name': this.infoChild
              }]
            }
          });
          this.infoChild = [];
        });

      }
      console.log("current data", this.information);

    });

  }

}
```

I have tried to call api with **constructor()** also with **ngOnInit() & ionViewDidLoad() ** data is getting properly but not reflecting on my view/html page.

My Html code is as follows:

```
<accordion *ngFor="let catParent of information" [title]="catParent.items.name">
      <!-- (click)="itemSelected(item)" -->
      <ion-list *ngFor="let catChild of catParent.items.children">
          <button ion-item *ngFor="let catChildName of catChild.name">
            {{ catChildName }}
          </button>
        </ion-list>
  </accordion>
```

so when I click on category tab api is calling and getting response but not able to see this result on my view page, now if I click on any other tab and again click on category tab then I am able to see this data.

As I am new to ionic 2 I am not able to fix this issue.
Can any one please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's best practice to fire HTTP requests from service or provider class
2. [IonViewDidLoad](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) runs only when the page is loaded so the empty page will be loaded before the HTTP request is fired.
3. Use [IonViewCanEnter](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) which can run before the view renders
4. Display loading using [ionic loading component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) so user will know something is happening in the background

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your accordion with a div containing a condition on your information data :

```
<div *ngIf="information.length>0;else noData">
    <accordion *ngFor="let catParent of information" [title]="catParent.items.name">
          ...
    </accordion>
</div>

<ng-template #noData>Loading accordion...</ng-template>
```

Comment: This might not be the best way, but it sure worked for me!  I may think about revisiting later.  Thank you